# What should be the return type of function that is run async

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

I was just trying out this sample to understand future and promise.

```
void func(std::promise<int>& p) {
  p.set_value (0);
}

int main ()
{
  std::promise<int> p;                      
  std::future<int> f = p.get_future(); 
  std::thread t(func, std::ref(p));  
  int x = fut.get();            

  t.join();
  return 0;
}
```

Is it ok if the return type of `func`is void? If yes, can the return type be `void` if it is used with `std::async`

```
 std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async,  func);
```

Is the return of async deduced to `std::future< int >` if the return type of `func` is `void`?

Please clarify about the return type of the function responsible for setting the promise.

also, should func be designed based on how it **could** be used?

Comment: One question per question please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example the function run by the [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) constructor can return a value or not, the value is ignored.

With a [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) call the return value of the supplied function (as determined by [std::result_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)) sets the template type of the returned [std::future](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future):

```
// function returns an int so std::async() returns a std::future<int>
std::future<int> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, []{ return 1; });
```

According to the `C++11` standard:

**30.6.8 Function template async**

> **4** Returns: An object of type `future<typename result_of<F(Args...)>::type>` that refers to the shared state created by this call to async.

So in your first example it doesn't matter what the return type of the function is because its the body of the function that sets the `std::promise`, not the return value.

With an `std::async()`, however, the return statement must return the shared value to the `std::future`.